# How to Spawn Objects in Unity3D with a Minimum Distance between

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am Programming a random `"Stone" Spawner` and have a big problem at the moment. I have some ideas how to fix it, but want to know a performance friendly way to do it.

So my way to `Spawn the Objects on the Sphere Surface` is this one:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 centerOfSphere = new Vector3(0, 5000, 0);
    public float radiusOfSphere = 5000.0f;

    public List<GameObject> stones;
    public int stonesToSpawn = 1;

    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 center = transform.position + centerOfSphere;       //Setting the center position of the Sphere

        //This for loop is spawning the Stones on a random position on Sphere Surface
        for (int i = 0; i < stonesToSpawn; i++)
        {
            Vector3 pos = RandomCircle(center, radiusOfSphere);
            Quaternion rot = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.forward, center - pos);
            Instantiate(stones[Random.Range(0, stones.Count)], pos, rot);
        }
    }

    //Method returns a Random Position on a Sphere
    Vector3 RandomCircle(Vector3 center, float radius) 
    {
        float alpha = UnityEngine.Random.value * 360;
        float beta = UnityEngine.Random.value * 360;
        Vector3 pos;
        pos.x = radius * Mathf.Cos(beta) * Mathf.Cos(alpha);
        pos.y = radius * Mathf.Cos(beta) * Mathf.Sin(alpha);
        pos.z = radius * Mathf.Sin(beta);

        return pos;
    }
}
```

So thank you for your following explanations! **:)**

Comment: The center of the object should be an random angle off the z-axis from -90 to +90 degrees and then rotated random around z-zxis from 0 to 360 degrees..

Comment: You know there already is [`center + Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized * radius`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-insideUnitCircle.html), [`center + Random.onUnitSphere * radius`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-onUnitSphere.html) etc

Comment: @derHugo Hahaha, where have you been before? I spent about 10 hours trying to find the right formula to get random points on a spherical surface: D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said to make your live one step easier simply use [`Random.onUnitSphere`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-onUnitSphere.html) so your entire method `RandomCircle` (change that name btw!) can be shrinked to

```
private Vector3 RandomOnSphere(Vector3 center, float radius)
{
    return center + Random.onUnitSphere * radius;
}
```

And then in order to have a minimum distance between them there are probably multiple ways but I guess the simplest - brute force - way would be:

- store already used positions
- when you get a new random position check the distance to already existing ones
- keep get new random positions until you have found one, that is not too close to an already existing one

This depends of course a lot on your use case and the amount of objects and the minimum distance etc - in other words I leave it up to you to assure that the requested amount and minimum distance is doable at all with the given sphere radius.

You could always leave an "emergency exit" and give up after e.g. 100 attempts.

Something like e.g.

```
// Linq offers some handy query shorthands that allow to shorten
// long foreach loops into single calls
using System.Linq;

...

private const int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 100;

public float minimumDistance = 1f;

void Start()
{
    var center = transform.position + centerOfSphere;

    // It is cheaper to use with square magnitudes
    var minDistanceSqr = minimumDistance * minimumDistance;

    // For storing the already used positions
    // Already initialize with the correct capacity, this saves resources
    var usedPositions = new List<Vector3>(stonesToSpawn);

    for (int i = 0; i < stonesToSpawn; i++)
    {
        // Keep track of the attempts (for the emergency break)
        var attempts = 0;
        Vector3 pos = Vector3.zero;
        do
        {
            // Get a new random position
            pos = RandomOnSphere(center, radiusOfSphere);
            // increase the attempts
            attempts++;

            // We couldn't find a "free" position within the 100 attempts :(
            if(attempts >= MAX_ATTEMPTS)
            {
                throw new Exception ("Unable to find a free spot! :'(");
            }
        }
        // As the name suggests this checks if any "p" in "usedPositions" is too close to the given "pos"
        while(usedPositions.Any(p => (p - pos).sqrMagnitude <= minDistanceSqr)));
        
        var rot = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.forward, center - pos);
        Instantiate(stones[Random.Range(0, stones.Count)], pos, rot);

        // Finally add this position to the used ones so the next iteration
        // also checks against this position
        usedPositions.Add(pos);
    }
}
```

Where

```
usedPositions.Any(p => (p - pos).sqrMagnitude <= minDistanceSqr))
```

basically equals doing something like

```
private bool AnyPointTooClose(Vector3 pos, List<Vector3> usedPositions, float minDistanceSqr)
{
    foreach(var p in usedPositions)
    {
        if((p - pos).sqrMagnitude <= minDistanceSqr)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

if that's better to understand for you

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot :) I hope this answer will help other People too :)